# File upload through node proxy

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I'm working with a node proxy server to forward the API requests to another server. This is working fine, but not for file upload. Apparently the headers are set properly, but somehow the image is not processed to the "final" server. What should I do?. Thanks!

```
    function pipeRequest(client_req, client_res, method) {
        var options = {
           hostname: HOSTNAME,
           port: PORT,
            path: client_req.url,
            method: method
        };

        var proxy = http.request(options, function (res) {
           res.pipe(client_res, {
              end: true
           });
         });

         if(client_req.url === "/ops/blong/image/upload"){
            console.log(client_req.headers['content-type']);
         }

         client_req.pipe(proxy, {
            end: true
         });
     }

    function onRequest(client_req, client_res) {
          var my_path = url.parse(client_req.url).pathname,
          full_path = path.join(process.cwd(), my_path);

         //Forward API calls
         if (client_req.method === 'POST') {
              pipeRequest(client_req, client_res, 'POST');

              //Return local files for static content
         }  else {
               filesys.exists(full_path, function (exists) {
                 bla bla bla....
```

Comment: Did you ever make this work? I'm sort of trying the same thing (the proxy upload should be streaming though): https://gist.github.com/Raffiki/2674a5646e7fb6dedadb